# gehabt haben vs. Plusquamperfekt

Tags: grammar, tense

Ich höre immer wieder Sätze wie:

> Du hast die Schlüssel verloren gehabt.

Meine starke Vermutung ist, dass es sich hier um eine umgangssprachliche, nicht ganz korrekte Alternative zu

> Du hattest die Schlüssel verloren.

handelt.

Ist die erste Form denn nun korrekt oder nicht - oder gar falsch? Gibt es Bedeutungsnuancen gegenüber dem zweiten Beispiel?

Comment: http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppeltes_Perfekt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wenn im Präteritum erzählt wird, wird die Vorvergangenheit normalerweise durch das Plusquamperfekt ausgedrückt (diese Form drückt aus, dass ein Sachverhalt vor einem anderen in der Vergangenheit liegenden Sachverhalt stattgefunden hat):

> Als er kam, hatten wir schon gegessen.

Die Perfekt-Form mit einem zusätzlichen *gehabt* wird in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* als **Doppelperfekt** bezeichnet:

> Als er kam, haben wir schon gegessen gehabt.

Diese Verwendung des Doppelperfekts als Ersatz für das Plusquamperfekt ist standardsprachlich nicht korrekt. Sie kommt allerdings in verschiedenen regionalen Umgangssprachen vor allem im Süden des deutschen Sprachgebiets vor. Besonders dort, wo umgangssprachlich häufig das Perfekt (anstelle des Präteritums) als Erzähltempus verwendet wird, tritt als Ausdruck der Vorvergangenheit das Doppelperfekt (anstelle des Plusquamperfekts) auf.

Answer (score 1):

DisplayName führt einen interessanten Punkt auf. Tatsächlich kann haben + Partizip Perfekt in manchen Fällen auch als eine Art des Zustandspassiv (Präsens) gedeutet werden:

> Der Hund hat die Pfote verbunden.

Dies funktioniert nur, weil das Weltwissen keinen sich die Pfote verbindenden Hund zulässt. Das Perfekt dieses Passivs entspricht dem Doppelperfekt:

> Der Hund hat die Pfote verbunden gehabt (und heute nicht mehr).

Der verlorene Schlüssel kann in beide Kategorien fallen, weil man es als Zustand deuten kann. Bei "Ich habe gearbeitet gehabt" ist die Doppelperfektdeutung hingegen zwingend.

Hört man das Doppelperfekt von Hochdeutschsprechern, muss man daher eher auf ein Zustandspassiv tippen, wenn es passt.

Der Grammatikduden akzeptiert übrigens das Doppelplusquamperfekt als zusätzliche Zeitstufe, weil es in einem Text von Goethe vorkommt.

Answer (score 0):

Vorgestern hast du die Schlüssel  verloren gehabt. Heute nicht mehr.

Du hattest die Schlüssel verloren, nicht ich.

Unterschied:

1. Fokus auf Zeitebene.
2. Fokus auf Subjektebene.

Comment: Antwort geht nicht auf die 2 Fragen ein und ist in sich zu kurz gefasst, um verstanden werden zu können, z.B. unklar, zwischen welchen 2 Dingen der Unterschied gemeint ist.